# CombineLatest is triggered although sources did not change

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable, combinelatest

I am using Angular as the frontend

```
grid$: Observable < any[][] > | null = null
ngOnInit() {
    this.grid$ = combineLatest([this.route.queryParams, source1, source2])
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                 window.scroll(0,0) // go to top when route params change
                //do something with the sources and route params
                return grid;
            })
        )
}
```

I am using `grid$` with async pipe

```
<ng-container *ngIf="grid$ | async as grid>
<div *ngFor="let column of columns>
    <div *ngFor="let analyse of grid[column]"> ... </div>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

which is working fine.

Now I want to change the grid after specific events occured

```
changeGrid() {
    // I also tried to just use map without assignment and return a new grid but then nothing happens
    this.grid$ = this.grid$.pipe(
        map(grid => {
            // do something with grid
            return grid;
        })
    }
}
```

which is also working. The only side effect I have is that `combineLatest` is triggered as well although sources did not change so that you scroll automatically to the top again which is not intended. Could someone explain me why? I tried it with `distinctUntilChanged` in `combineLatest` but it is not triggered anymore when using `changeGrid()`. I used `distinctUntilChanged` in the following way

```
distinctUntilChanged((prev,curr) => 
{ 
    return prev[0].get("id") != curr[0].get("id")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, by writing `this.grid$ = ...` you lose the memory reference to its previous value. This means you can't stop the previous observable, which is in the combineLatest. This might be the cause of your issue.

Second, Since you use the queryParams observable, it means that on every query param change, your observable gets triggered. You didn't give enough code to show if it's the case, but this also might be the other cause of your issue.

Finally, `distinctUntilChanged` compares memory references : when being used with `combineLatest`, unless you provide a function to it, the operaor is useless (a new array is being created each time the combineLatest emits).

Comment: I need the id of the params so I used distinctUntilChanged in the following way ```distinctUntilChanged((prev,curr) => { return prev[0].get("id") != curr[0].get("id")})```  but it is not triggered anymore, I checked it with console.log and nothing appears on the console anymore

Comment: I also tried in ```changeGrid()``` to only use ```map``` to transform the grid and return a new one without new assignment but then nothing happens.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue on stackblitz

Comment: Yes, I will in a moment.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to avoid the first problem? How can we stop the previous observables from executing again when changing the value of  ```grid$``` ?

Comment: @Invader you would have to use a `Subscription` to stop them, or the operator `takeUntil`

Comment: I tried it. My goal is that everytime the route params change (the id) I want to build a new grid with limited elements. I am using ``` combineLatest``` in order to listen to changes of ```source1``` and ```source2``` so that the grid is built when the values (arrays) are ready because they are observables based on a ```BehaviorSubject``` in a service using ```asObservable()```. With ```changeGrid``` I append new elements to that grid. But when the id changes (queryParam) then the newly build grid contains the number of elements of the previous grid instead of the specified number